# Is using "See you soon" as a sign appropriate for a letter to a pen-friend?

Tags: exam-questions, writing

If a pen-friend is a person whom you likely won't see in the future, can we write "see you soon" at the end of an informal letter? It seems weird to me, but what would you say?  My question is related to exam preparation, so such a detail is essential. Thanks in advance

Comment: Be in touch soon

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use "See you soon" in this context.

You could say "I'll write again soon" or "till next time" or "All the best".  There are lots of casual sign offs:

- Best,
- Your friend,
- Take care,
- Be in touch soon,
- Yours,

Followed by your name or signature.

For an exam, use whatever your teacher tells you to write. Or copy the example in the textbook.

For a real pen pal, you can also copy your pen pal.